# Conflicting traits with generic bound but not without for potential "downstream" implementations

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Excuse the large amounts of code here, but the minimal example is tricky to explain, I've tried to make it as short as possible.  I am trying to implement a generic trait, over a generic type, with a generic bound, and this causes the compiler error:

```
note: downstream crates may implement trait `Named<_>` for type `ExampleThing`
```

What's strange is this works perfectly fine is Named does not take a generic parameter, so I don't understand why this causes a problem, and how to fix it.

**Minimally Broken Example**

(Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6d0bdb30f1977318a9613b4629c5be80)

The explanation of the code is probably easiest reading the comments.  In real world context `Named` is the trait that is being introduced to existing code base of `Talk<K>` and `make_talk<T, K>`.

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

/// This trait is to be implemented by downstream crates for objects that talk
/// In order to break things there is a spurious extra piece of information of
/// generic type K that is to be included in the message
pub trait Talks<K> {
    fn say(&self, extra: K);
}

/// A normal use case
pub struct ExampleThing(u64);

/// So we implement it manually like this
impl<K> Talks<K> for ExampleThing where K: Debug {
    fn say(&self, extra: K) {
        println!("I have the number {} [extra: {:?}]", self.0, extra);
    }
}

/// Then this can make any that implemnets Talk, talk.  We can always pass some
/// extra bit of info of type K to include in the message
pub fn make_talk<T, K>(thing: T, extra: K) where T: Talks<K> {
    thing.say(extra);
}

/// A large collection of objects are named, exposing a name method,
/// and they are capable of including the extra info 
pub trait Named<K> {
    fn name(&self, extra: K) -> String;
}

/// For example this guy
pub struct Person{ name: String }

impl<K> Named<K> for Person where K: Debug {
    fn name(&self, extra: K) -> String {
        format!("{:?} of {:?}" , self.name.clone(), extra)
    }
}

/// And then we can try make it so that all things that implement Name
/// introduce themselves automatically using Name
impl<K, T> Talks<K> for T where 
K: Debug,
T: Named<K>
{
    fn say(&self, extra: K) {
        println!("My name is {}", self.name(extra))
    }
}

fn main() { 
    let example = ExampleThing(42);
    make_talk(example, "Did it work?");
    let person = Person{name: "Bob".to_string()};
    make_talk(person, 1234);
}
```

produces this error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Talks<_>` for type `ExampleThing`
  --> src/main.rs:43:1
   |
14 |   impl<K> Talks<K> for ExampleThing where K: Debug {
   |   ------------------------------------------------ first implementation here
...
43 | / impl<K, T> Talks<K> for T where 
44 | | K: Debug,
45 | | T: Named<K>
   | |___________^ conflicting implementation for `ExampleThing`
   |
   = note: downstream crates may implement trait `Named<_>` for type `ExampleThing`
```

**Tiny change that works**

If we remove the generic bound `Named<K>` and replace it with `Named<u64>` then all is fine:

```
impl<K, T> Talks<K> for T where 
K: Debug,
T: Named<u64>
{
    fn say(&self, extra: K) {
        println!("My name is {}", self.name(999))
    }
}
```

and this outputs:

```
I have the number 42 [extra: "Did it work?"]
My name is "Bob" of 999
```

**Question**

What is going on here?  How can I fix this so that the `extra` field of type `K` can be passed into `Named<K>` in the blanket implementation.  The error message about downstream crates is confusing as it only applies when the trait bound includes K.

Comment: Can a type only ever implement `Named<K>` for two different `K`s?

Comment: Also, anything you can say about the specific circumstances in which `Named` is implemented may help.

Comment: The full complete source code is in the question.  I'd expect Named<K> to always be given generic implementation, since that extra is anything.  Notice though that the working version still implements Named<K>, it is just the bound on Talks<K>::T that is concrete.

Comment: Can you move the generic parameter to the `name()` method instead of the trait?

Comment: That does indeed work - and quite a practical solution, so I'd give you the answer for that alone.  However, the question still remains - why is this happening?  Is this a bug in the compiler, an intentional but unfortunate shortcoming, or a genuine positive reason that it should behave like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without generic parameter, no one can write an implementation of `Named` for `ExampleThing` but you. Such impl would make the two impls `impl Talks for ExampleThing` and `impl<T: Named> Talks for T` conflicting. However, since only you can write this impl (since no other crate owns the type or the trait), the compiler can just check that such impl does not exist and move on.

However, with `Named` having a generic parameter, not only the owner of the trait (`Named`) or the owner of the type (`ExampleThing`) can write such impl, but also the owner of the generic parameter (`SomeType` in `impl Named<SomeType> for ExampleThing`). So you can no longer ensure your implementations don't conflict, and this is why the compiler complains.

You can move the generic parameter to the method to solve this.

Comment: Indeed, but the confusion is that even if we keep Name<K> but trait bound where T: Named<u64> the compiler is happy.  Yet a downstream implementation of Named<K> would still conflict with Talks for T: Named<u64>

Comment: @Corvus No, because again, nobody can implement `Named<u64>` for `ExampleThing` but you, since `u64` is a foreign type.